# Omniauth YouTube help parsing response

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, youtube-api, omniauth

I have omniauth set up correctly and I am able to parse several other provider responses, including some of the attributes for a YouTube user but I am not able to get the YouTube user's link to their channel. Here is what the response looks like, I am trying to get the link on the last line:

```
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: youtube
uid: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/DLjkduRouoiweRktkkl
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  uid: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/DLjkduRouoiweRktkkl
  nickname: Example User
  email: exampleuser@gmail.com
  first_name: Example
  last_name: User
  image: http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-7vCkdsSDAfsU/AAAAAAAAAAA/kjRe3kjk/s88-c-k/photo.jpg
  description: 
  location: Example City CA, US
  channel_title: Example User
  subscribers_count: '66'
credentials: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  token: kh58.lkjASDF93-W2-ADFJkjfdo498_W8IWnjWTWY
  expires_at: 1354004818
  expires: true
extra: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  user_hash: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    xmlns: http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
    xmlns$media: http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/
    xmlns$gd: http://schemas.google.com/g/2005
    xmlns$yt: http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007
    id: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      $t: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/DLjkduRouoiweRktkkl
    published: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      $t: '2012-02-14T23:39:43.000Z'
    updated: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      $t: '2012-11-27T06:07:22.000Z'
    category:
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      scheme: http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind
      term: http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#userProfile
    title: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      $t: Example User
      type: text
    content: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      $t: Example user channel description
      type: text
    link:
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      rel: alternate
      type: text/html
      href: http://www.youtube.com/channel/kljasdSDAF98324
      .
      .
      .
```

I can get to things like "nickname" at the top by doing this in my user model:

```
def add_omniauth(auth)
  user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
end
```

But how on earth do I get to that URL at the very bottom? I tried:

```
user.link = auth["extra"]["user_hash"]["link"]["href"]
```

but to no avail. As a rails and ruby newbie, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so as it turns out, link: in the youtube response is an array. You can tell because it isn't listed as a hash next to it. I learned that after speaking with a friend of mine over here. So in order to get that link at the bottom of the response:

```
self.url = auth["extra"]["user_hash"]["link"].first["href"]
```